# $C^1(\mathbb{T})$ is dense in $C(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the $1$-dimensional continuous torus.
>
> Then $C^1(\mathbb{T})$ is dense in $C(\mathbb{T})$ under the uniform topology.

From my understanding, I would have to prove that every continuous function on the torus is either a function with continuous derivative or a limit of functions with continuous derivatives (on the torus).
However, this doesn't seem obvious to me (and the statement is just said without a proof).
Can anyone help?

Comment: Use [Fejer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Fej%C3%A9r's%20theorem%2C%20named,on%20%5B%2D%CF%80%2C%CF%80%5D.). Remember that you can think of functions on $\mathbb{T}$ as periodic functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Trigonometric polynomials (or equivalently, polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$ restricted to $\mathbb{T}$) are dense in $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{T})$ and are smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e_n: \mathbb T \to \mathbb T$, for $n\in \mathbb Z$, be defined by $e_n(z) = z^n$ (I identify $\mathbb T$ with $\{z\in \mathbb C: |z| = 1\}$).

In fact the linear span of $\{e_n:n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is alredy dense in $C(\mathbb T)$. This is a classical application of the Stone Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: The complex version of Stoen-Weierstrass that is.